# Prove of a regular parametrized surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $\alpha$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha(t)=(t,t^{2},t^{3})\hspace{0.5cm}t\in \mathbb{R}
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
X(u,v)=\alpha(t)+u\alpha'(t)
\end{eqnarray*}
for $u\in (0,\infty)$. Show that $X$ is a regular parametrized surface.

---

For this I tried to show that $X$ is parametrized so, $x$ is differential in the sense that each coordenate function is diferential, and for show that $dX_{q}$ is one-to one I have this:
\begin{eqnarray*}
dX_{q}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
2t&2t+2u\\
3t^{2}&3t^{2}+6ut
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
but I have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,t)}=2u \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{\partial(x,z)}{\partial(u,t)}=6ut \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial(u,t)}=6ut^2
\end{eqnarray*}
I don't know how can I conclude that $dX_{q}$ is one to one and for show that $x$ is a homeomorphism I've tried to use this proposition

### [image]

But I have trouble when I try to show that $x$ is injective, Cause if $X(u_{1},t_{1})=X(u_{2},t_{2})$ then:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             t_{1}+u_{1} = t_{2}+u_{2}  \\
             \\ t_{1}^{2}+2u_{1}t_{1} = t_{2}^{2}+2u_{2}t_{2}  \\
             \\ t_{1}^{3}+3u_{1}+t_{1}^{2} =t_{2}^{3}+3u_{2}+t_{2}^{2}
             \end{array}
   \right. 
\end{eqnarray}
so I don't If I go on right way for show that $X$ parametrized and if is regular surface. If you can help me with ideas or corrections I will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Pay attention to detail. Note that $u>0$.

Comment: In this case. Can I garantice that $6ut^2 \neq 0$ and $6ut \neq 0$?

Comment: Why are you trying to guarantee all three terms are nonzero?

Comment: Cause I want guarantee that $dx_{q}$ es injective

Comment: Relearn your definitions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ohh.. I get it I just have to show that one is non zero, right?

Comment: Yup, that’s right.